# Toggle a full screen program on i3

Tags: ubuntu, fullscreen, i3-window-manager

I want to make some sort of status window/system monitor with something like node-WebKit on my computer, which is pretty trivial. The thing is, I would like to be able to have a keyboard command in i3 to toggle this as full screen regardless of which workspace in i3 that I am in. How can I do this?

Comment: do you mean like pressing $meta+f ?

Comment: no, like a specific window/program will take up the whole screen, regardless of the workspace I am in. Similar to the gnome launcher or any program launcher really. There is probably a way to do this without using i3, like how i3 does not deal with wallpapers.

Comment: That's difficult. Afaik you can only toggle fullscreen on the currently focused containter.  If you have access to theprgroam itself, you can make it tell to go inot fullscreen, that works.

Comment: The only thing I can think of was changing focus like described [here](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_focusing_moving_containers) to change focus to the container in question, but sadly you cannot give certain criteria, but only move left/right/etc. Then one could just `exec fullscreen`. `for_window` seems not to work.

Answer (score 2):

You could put the following two lines into your *i3* configuration:

```
for_window [title="^WINDOW_TITLE$"] mark "STATWIN", move scratchpad
bindsym Mod4+s [con_mark="^STATWIN$"] fullscreen enable, scratchpad show
```

Where `WINDOW__TITLE` is the exact title of your status window and `Mod4+s` (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>) the intended shortcut. If you press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> it will either show the window fullscreen on the current workspace or hide it if it is already there.

#### Explanation:

1. Initialization:

   ```
   for_window [title="^WINDOW_TITLE$"] mark "STATWIN", move scratchpad
   ```

   - `for_window` can be used to run specific commands for windows that match the given criteria (here `title="^WINDOWS_TITLE$"`) when they are created. That means that the title has to match the initial title of the window. There are also other criteria like `class` or `instance`. Depending on your program you may need to use something other than `title` or even a combination of criteria (See [the section on criteria in the i3 User's Guide](http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_list_of_commands) for more information)
   - `mark` puts an unique label onto a window, that can later be used in with the `con_mark` criterion to refer to that window. Here the label is `STATWIN`
   - `,`: It is important to note that `,` is used to chain commands instead of `;`. Window criteria (`[...]`) are only applied until the next `;` (or the end of the line, of course).
   - `move scratchpad` moves the window to the Scratchpad, which can be used for windows, to which you want to have easy access. (See [the section on Scratchpad in the User's Guide](http://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#_scratchpad))
2. Accessing the window

   ```
   bindsym Mod4+s [con_mark="^STATWIN$"] fullscreen enable, scratchpad show
   ```

   - `bindsym` binds a command to a shortcut (here `Mod4+s`)
   - the list of criteria - `[con_mark="^STATWIN$"]` - tells *i3* to run the following commands for all windows matching all criteria (instead of the currently focused window). Criteria are matched as regular expressions, so you can/should use `^` and `$` to denote the start and end of a string, respectively. Here the only criterion is `con_mark="^STATWIN$"`, matching the window (there can only be one) marked with `STATWIN` (exactly), which was done in the Initialization.
   - `fullscreen enable` needs to be done (everytime) as windows from the Scratchpad are usually shown as floating windows. (To be exact: while the fullscreen status can be set on a Scratchpad window at any time (visible or not), the status will be removed, when the window is hidden by `scratchpad show`. If the window was invisible when setting fullscreen, it will remain invisible but will appear fullscreen on `scratchpad show`)
   - again `,` needs to be used to delimit commands because the criterion should apply to both commands
   - `scratchpad show` makes the window visible on the current workspace if it was not on the current workspace before. If it was already on the current workspace the window will be hidden.